# In layman's terms, what does the Price equation say?

Tags: statistics, biology

I am trying to understand what the Price equation says, based on the associated Wikepedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_equation.  The equation they give is:
$$ \Delta z =  \frac{1}{w}  cov(w_i,z_i) + \frac{1}{w} E(w_i \Delta z_i) $$
where z is the frequency of a trait and w is the fitness of the trait, which I assume means number of viable offspring.

Here is my stab at an explanation.  The first term gives the change in frequency assuming that the $w_i$ terms stay constant and the second term gives the frequency change due to changes to $w_i$ caused by mutation.  I am sure that is overly simplistic if not flat out wrong.  Am I close?  How does the equation relate to group selection?

Answer (score 1):

Andy Gardner wrote a piece describing the equation for the journal Current Biology http://www.cell.com/current-biology/pdf/S0960-9822(08)00008-0.pdf. I reproduce some of his description of the equation below (note that I have written the Price equation as Gardner has it in his paper).

"The Price equation is a simple mathematical statement about change. In its usual formulation, it describes how the average value of any character — body weight, antler size, proclivity to altruism — changes in a biological population from one
generation to the next.

Price denoted
the individual’s character value as z,
its number of offspring as w, and the
discrepancy between the character
values of itself and its offspring as
∆z, and showed that the change
in the population average value of
the character between parent and
offspring generations is $$ \Delta \bar{z} =  cov(\frac{w}{\bar{w}},z) +  E(\frac{w}{\bar{w}}, \Delta z) $$

The Price equation separates the
total change into two component
parts. The first part is the change
that can be ascribed to the action
of selection, and this takes the form
of a statistical covariance between
individuals’ character values (z) and
their relative reproductive success
$(w/\bar{w})$.

For example, if individuals
with larger values of the character of
interest tend to have more offspring,
then the covariance is positive
and selection acts to increase the
population average value of the
character.

The remainder term
takes the form of an expectation
(arithmetic average) describing how
offspring differ from their partners,
and this is denoted the change due
to transmission. If offspring are
identical copies of their parents, then
the transmission effect is zero and
selection is the only factor involved
in the evolution of the character.

However, offspring will often differ
from their parents, perhaps because
of mutation, or because their genes
are recombined in a new way, or
because of a change in their physical,
biological or cultural environment, and
in this case the transmission effect is
non-zero."